# all image object changing in one css after click

Tags: javascript, java, css, arrays, jsp

I am using below code to change one image from one div of html

```
$(this).parent().find("img").attr("src", "resources/vidal/images/accordion_down.svg");
```

but this code is changing my all image object available in that div with this image.

Comment: in your scenario .find('img') retrieves more than one image. Which one should be changed?

Comment: then what i should use, it should change only one image on which i am clicking.

Comment: you need to be more specific, which image: the first ? the last ? with a specific class ? etc

Comment: find image by id instead

Comment: why not simply this `$(this).attr("src", "resources/vidal/images/accordion_down.svg");` ?

Comment: Temani its not working actually my expectation is like i want to change that image only where i am clicking not all the images available in that div tag ,i dont aware about css that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class or id on the image you want to change.

```
$(this).parent().find("img#myImage").attr("src", "resources/vidal/images/accordion_down.svg");
```

Comment: sir your previous answer was working please provide it again, but how i can pass that id dynamically in my js or jquery because so many image id is there. and hyperlink is there also

Comment: out.println("<h6>");
                out.println("<a data-toggle=\"collapse\" href=\"#collapseOne\" aria-expanded=\"true\" aria-controls=\"collapseOne\" class=\"\" style=\"color:white;font-size: 15px;\">");
                out.println("<img src=\""+webcontext+"/resources/vidal/images/accordion_down.svg\" alt=\"accordion_down\">");
                out.println("Confidence Level");
                out.println("</a>");
                out.println("</h6>");
                out.println("</div>");

Comment: I tried with buttons:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Try jQuery Online</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<input type='button' value='Button 1'>
<input type='button' value='Button 2'>
<input type='button' value='Button 3'>

<script>
debugger;
$("input[type=button]").click(function(){
    debugger;
    $(this).attr("style", "background:red");
})
console.log($(this).find("myImage"));

</script>
</body>
</html>

Run this code in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_jquery_editor.php

Comment: Please let me know if it is what you need.

Comment: what image id I need to pass that image id is under <a> tag <a><img id="something"></img></a> , but what click function i am performing that is i performing on clcik of hyperlink means <a> tag so on that click how i will get image tag id to pass in above given query by you

Comment: Like below i am trying But getting Value Undefined.                                                   alert($("a > img.active").attr("id"));
      alert($(".active").attr("id"));
      alert($(".active").children("img").attr("id"));

Comment: Thanks Issue has been resolved .. getting id of image under <a> tag by using  var imageid=$(this).parent().find("img").attr("id");

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the following?

```
$("img").click(function(){
    $(this).attr("src", "resources/vidal/images/accordion_down.svg");
});
```